# Console displays Uncaught SecurityError

Tags: jquery, http, https

I'm not sure how I can fix the error below. Can somebody help me out?

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://mysite.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an https url from within a http website. HTTPS and HTTP are different protocol and is causing a mismatch.

I think the following link might help:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ODpydGiCgiE

```
if you want to access frames in a iframe you can change top with 
parent.frames only for accessing frames in the iframe who execute javascript.
try to change top with parent.frames

return top.frames;

return parent.frames;

in google chrome it work for me i can access all my frames in my iframe.
```

Or if you are just trying to access your own domain with different protocol, you can also try setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: I'm not sure where I have to change `top.frames` to `parent.frames`. Do you know where I can change this?

Comment: Alternatively, do you think the problem could be fixed if I just switched the rest of my site to https?

Comment: 'parent' in the iframe is the frame you call the iframe from.

Comment: and yes, it will fix if you just switch the whole site to https

Answer (score 0):

Try using // instead of specifying the protocol with http:// or https:// in the iFrame URL address source address. It should use the protocol of the site.