# Allowing a parent window to call a function on its child iframe of a different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe in which src is different domain, and I am trying to call a method in iframe from parent window. Then it is giving below:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://stage.xyz.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

On main window I have this:

```
launchUPwidget(widgetParams);
function launchUPwidget(widgetParams){
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.invokeUPWidget(widgetParams);       
}
```

On iframe:

```
window.invokeUPWidget = invokeWidget;
```

So how can I call a function in child iframe form parent window where iframe src is different domain?

here protocals are same but the domains are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console displays Uncaught SecurityError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900897/console-displays-uncaught-securityerror)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an `<iframe>` with Javascript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it.
For the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) every browser blocks any script trying to access a frame with a different origin.

Even though same-origin policy blocks scripts from accessing the content of sites with a different origin, if you own both the pages, you can work around this problem using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and its relative message event to send messages between the two pages, like this:

In your main page:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('your-frame-id');

frame.contentWindow.postMessage(/*any variable or object here*/, '*');
```

In your  (contained in the main page):

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

    // IMPORTANT: Check the origin of the data!
    if (event.origin.indexOf('http://yoursite.com')) {
        // The data has been sent from your site

        // The data sent with postMessage is stored in event.data
        console.log(event.data);
    } else {
        // The data hasn't been sent from your site!
        // Be careful! Do not use it.
        return;
    }
});
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame). You can read about it more there.